# Почему при таком коде в html на ноутбуке текст по центру а на телефоне нет

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.first-line {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 140px;
  text-shadow: 15px 15px 6px black;
}

.second-line {
  text-shadow: 15px 15px 6px black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.imgone {
  margin-top: -100px;
  width: 1482px;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0px auto 20px;
  display: block;
}

.one {
  margin-top: -400px;
}

.three-line {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 400px;
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor=''>
  <img class='imgone' src='https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-entity_search/2487574/434829330/orig' />
  <div class='one'>
    <h1 class='first-line'>МАНУЛ</h1>
    <h2 class='second-line'>ывмывмывмывмвмвым</h2>
  </div>
  <h2 class='three-line'>ывмывмвымвы<br>ывмвымвымыв<br>мвымывмвымвым<br></h2>
</body>
```